# How to create XML from array in php with xmlns

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I need to create xml from array in php with xmlns

here is my array and desired output xml

```
 <?php 

$aray= array(
'foo' => '12',
'boo' => '15',
'bar' => 'test value', 
);
?>
```

desired output

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<opertaion xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<foo xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">12</foo>    
<boo xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">15</boo>   
<bar xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">test value</bar>     
</opertaion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through all the values inside your array and append the data to an output variable.

```
<?php
    $aray= array(
        'foo' => '12',
        'boo' => '15',
        'bar' => 'test value', 
    );

    $output = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"><opertaion xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $output .= '<'.$key.' xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">'.$value.'</'.$key.'>';
    }

    $output .= '</opertaion>';
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Is the page XML only? Then you should use `header("Content-type: text/xml");` above everything.